# Specify a job name while creating a Dataproc job using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, terraform

I am creating a Dataproc job using Terraform using this script format:

```
resource "google_dataproc_job" "pyspark" {
  region       = google_dataproc_cluster.mycluster.region
  force_delete = true
  placement {
    cluster_name = google_dataproc_cluster.mycluster.name
  }

  pyspark_config {
    main_python_file_uri = "gs://dataproc-examples-2f10d78d114f6aaec76462e3c310f31f/src/pyspark/hello-world/hello-world.py"
    properties = {
      "spark.logConf" = "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Running this json creates a job with a random name. But I want to specify a job name.
I tried using name = "my-job-name", but it just throws an error.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting ? Also I guess you need to specify the name within reference block. Somewhat like **`reference {job = “job name”}`**

Comment: Could maybe the `labels` block be used to specify a name for the job?

Comment: yeah reference {job = “job name”} worked! thank you